# Timing of ability when Control Minion used

Tags: smash-up

When the Geeks use "Control Minion" on a played minion (a Shoggoth in the case in question), who gets the benefit of making other players draw Madness or destroy a minion?

Answer (score 2):

**The controller steals the effect.**

As long as you play Control Minion according to its special, the controller uses the minion's entry effect. Otherwise, the card would say "Special: Play **after** another player plays a minion."

The game uses "after" a minion is played to clarify that its entry effects occur first (such as with the Leprechaun). That wording isn't used here.